# What exactly does $ match in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Until a few minutes ago, I believed that [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl)'s `$` matches any kind of end of line. Unfortunatly, my assumption turns out to be wrong.

The following script removes the word *end* only for `$string3`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string1 = " match to the end" . chr(13);
my $string2 = " match to the end" . chr(13) . chr(10);
my $string3 = " match to the end" .           chr(10);

$string1 =~ s/ end$//;
$string2 =~ s/ end$//;
$string3 =~ s/ end$//;

print "$string1\n";
print "$string2\n";
print "$string3\n";
```

But I am almost 75% sure that I have seen cases where `$` matched at least `chr(13).chr(10)`.

So, what exactly (and under what circumstances) does the `$` atom match?

Comment: You may have been reading a file in `:crlf` mode, so the file contained `chr(13).chr(10)` but the string you were matching against had only `chr(10)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` matches only the position before `\n`/`chr(10)` and not before `\r`/`chr(13)`.

It's very often misinterpreted to match before a `newline` character (in a lot of cases it's not causing problems), but to be strict it matches before a "linefeed" character **but not before a carriage return character!**

See *[Regex Tutorial - Start and End of String or Line Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)*.

Comment: Gosh darned newline conventions.

Comment: Indeed. There is no such thing as a `newline` character.

Comment: @Borodin, Unicode disagrees. U+000A is known by a few names including both LINE FEED and NEW LINE.

Comment: @ikegami: I am sure the `U+000A` code point is referred to as many things colloquially, but I have never seen a Unicode document that calls it `NEW LINE`. The nearest is `U+0085`, which is `NEL` or `NEXT LINE`.

Comment: @Borodin, You misunderstand if you think I mean those are colloquial names. Those are official Unicode names for U+000A. Specifically, U+000A is named `LINE FEED (LF)` and has the following aliases: `LINE FEED`, `NEW LINE`, `END OF LINE`, `LF`, `NL`, `EOL` (all case insensitive). I also see "`new line (NL)`" and "`end of line (EOL)`" in the code charts, but I don't see those anywhere in the database. Where did you look?

Answer (score 12):

First of all, it depends on whether the `/m` modifier is in effect or not.

With `/m` active, it matches before a `\n` character or at the end of the string.  It's equivalent to `(?=\n|\z)`.

Without `/m`, it matches before a `\n` character if that is the last character of the string, or at the end of the string.  It's equivalent to `(?=\n?\z)`.

It does not match a generic newline.  The `\R` metacharacter (introduced in 5.10.0) does that (but without the end-of-string property of `$`).  You can substitute `\R` for `\n` in one of the previous equivalencies to get a `$` work-alike that does match a generic newline.

Note that `\n` is not always `chr(10)`.  It depends on the platform.  Most platforms currently in use have `\n` meaning `chr(10)`, but that wasn't always the case.  For example, on older Macs, `\n` was `chr(13)` and `\r` was `chr(10)`.

Comment: The latter part of your answer is misleading, if not simply untrue. Internally, Perl *always* represents the platform's end of line sequence with `"\n"`, which is *always* `chr(10), or an ASCII `LF`. This is identical to what appears in an external file for Linux and Max OS X, but an extra IO layer translates it to and from `CR LF` on a Windows and DOS platform, and `CR` on Mac OS v9 and earlier. `"\r"` has never been anything other than `chr(13)`, or ASCII `CR`.

Comment: @Borodin However, one must be careful if one has to deal with files generated on a different platform.

Comment: @Boridin, You're wrong and cjm is correct. On MacOS builds, \n and \r matched/produced 0D and 0A respectively. That's why there's (obselete) recommendations to use `\x0D\x0A` for CGI output instead of `\r\n`. If what you say is true, those two would be equivalent. PerlIO layers didn't even exist back then.

Comment: @ikegami: thanks, I wasn't aware of that bizarre behaviour on legacy Mac systems. But I did include OS X amongst the systems that use `LF` as a line terminator.

Answer (score 1):

```
/$/
/$/m
```

are equivalent to

```
/(?=\n\z)|\z/
/(?=\n)|\z/
```

respectively. `\n` matches U+000A (LINE FEED aka NEWLINE) on all existing platforms.

Comment: While your equivalent regexs are correct as written, I think my versions are better.  Since `\z` is a zero-width assertion, it doesn't really matter whether it's inside `(?=...)`, but by moving the alternation inside the group, you can use it in a larger regex as-is.  With your versions, you'd need to use `(?:(?=\n\z)|\z)` to keep `|` from alternating more than it should.